# Retrieve coordinates from snapped points in Forge viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, forge, snapping

I want to snapp points in the model and retrieve their coordinates. I found the below code in Forge blog

```
this.points = [];
const result = this.snapper.getSnapResult();

            const { SnapType } = Autodesk.Viewing.MeasureCommon;

            switch (result.geomType) {
                case SnapType.SNAP_VERTEX:
                case SnapType.SNAP_MIDPOINT:
                case SnapType.SNAP_INTERSECTION:

     this.points.push(result.getGeometry());
```

Now Im able to get the coordinates of vertex and midpoints, but I want to actully get the coordinates of any snapped point of a Brep-line for instance. How is this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably referring to this [blog post](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/snappy-viewer-tools), right? The `SnapType` enumeration used in the blog lists all the types of snapping types the tool can detect. Other types you would probably have to detect yourself, for example, by shooting a ray to the scene based on the camera position and mouse cursor position, and finding whatever object of interest are nearby.

Comment: Yes I was referring to the blog you mentioned. If I used "SNAP_EDGE" (for rendering and snapping), Im able to retrive the vertex coordinates from the JSON-obejct, which arent actully the coordinates from the snapped point. Im kind of a new to this and the approach you mentioned sounds not doable for me. Are you aware if there is some similiar approach somewhere out there ?

Comment: Unfortunately no. If there's some other solution for this kind of snapping, I'm not aware of it.